# Single select Tag in Touch UI

Tags: aem

OOTB Tag has multi select functionality, Is it possible to create single select Tag in Touch UI? If yes, can you point me which js file I need to modify?

Answer (score 2):

The `cq:tags` property is rendered by `CUI.TagList` widget that can be found within `/etc/clientlibs/granite/coralui2/js/coral.js` script.

Reading it you can learn that the widget raises `itemadded` event which might be helpful for you to handle the singular tag handling. An example function that can catch the event might be placed in any clientlibs that will be attached to the admin interface such as `cq.authoring.dialog` clientlib.

```
$('*[data-fieldname="./cq:tags"]').on('itemadded', function(ev, value) {
    var el = $(ev.target),
        div = el.siblings('div'),
        input = div.find('input'),
        button = div.find('button');
    input.prop('disabled', true);
    button.remove();
}
```

To have the fully functional flow you need to handle the `itemremoved` event as well and make the input field enabled again as well as add the button back to the widget.

Comment: coral.js is not responsible for adding and removing tags. There is not metadata called "multiple" for tags which decide that it is a single or multi select Tags. By default it is true...i had to change it to false